# How do I turn gray wifi icon to blue?

Tags: wi-fi

I have been searching for answers and some suggestions doesn't seem to work.  I can connect to WiFi but I am not able to use it, (Facebook, Play store, Etc.) because the WiFi icon seem to turn into gray. What will I do??

Comment: Can any app connect to the internet? Can you e.g. use a web browser, and access any site? To what WiFi are you connecting? Is the connection established successfully? Are there any error messages shown?

Answer (score 0):

This, at least for me, happens when my device connects to Wi-Fi, but with wrong parameters. I fix this by entering the Wi-Fi settings, choosing "Static IP" instead of "DHCP", and then editing the network parameters manually, like this:

***These settings may be different on your router, so check that if it isn't working.***

- IP adress: 192.168.1.xx (replace xx with any number, avoid 2, 3 or 4, because there may be devices already connected with that adress)
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1
- Prefix lenght: 24
- DNS1: 8.8.8.8
- DNS2:8.8.4.4

Answer (score -1):

When you get internet access from wifi hotspot.That gray WiFi icon automatically turns to blue color.

Comment: Only if the device is able to access the Google servers.